# Flutter App Starts from splash screen, even when started from the background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background, razorpay

`When the user navigates to another app via our flutter app, and then comes back to the flutter app the flutter app gets started from the splash screen. Instead of the app to resume from where the user left of it starts from the splash screen. This happens only in some of the devices (low-end devices) and works perfectly fine for the high-end device. For example if the user wants to make a purchase (using razor pay) and selects the option to pay via google pay, the user will be directed to the google pay app, upon successful payment in google pay the user will be navigated back to the app but the app will again start from the splash screen instead of listening to the payment event

1. The user initiates a buy
2. Razor pay pop up opens up, the user chooses to pay via google pay
3. The user is navigated to the google pay app, and makes the purchase.
4. The user comes back to the flutter app, but instead of resuming where the user left of the app starts from the beginning that is the splash screen.
   The AndroidManifest.xml is as follows

   ```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.bynge.story">
        <queries>
            <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
            <!-- allows app to access Facebook app features -->
        </queries>
        <application android:label="Notion Press" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.Application">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="bynge_local_notification" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
                <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
                <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>

                <!-- Deep Links -->
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="bynge" android:host="app" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="bynge" android:host="series" android:pathPrefix="/seriesid/episodeid" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bynge.in" android:pathPrefix="/wa" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true"/>
            <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" android:exported="true"/>
            <meta-data android:name="CLEVERTAP_BACKGROUND_SYNC" android:value="1"/>
            <meta-data android:name="CLEVERTAP_NOTIFICATION_ICON" android:value="ic_launcher"/>
            <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
   ```

Comment: Please share your `AndroidManifest.xml` from `android/app/src/main`

Comment: Thank you Soo much for replying Alex Sunder Singh. I am adding the AndroidManifest.xml in the question

Answer (score 0):

> This happens only in some of the devices (low-end devices) and works perfectly fine for the high-end device.

It sounds like your device is running low on resources, so it is killing the app when it is in the background.  This is described in [Overview of memory management](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#SwitchingApps):

> If your app has a cached process and it retains resources that it currently does not need, then your app—even while the user is not using it— affects the system's overall performance. As the system runs low on resources like memory, it kills processes in the cache. The system also accounts for processes that hold onto the most memory and can terminate them to free up RAM.

To solve this, follow the advice on the same page:

> The less memory your app consumes while in the cache, the better its chances are not to be killed and to be able to quickly resume.

So, take a look at [lowering your app's memory usage](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory).